Should one read second Temple Jewish writings, to gain a better understanding of the world view of a first century New Testament writer and audience?
I have been taught that the Bible interprets itself,  and I do believe it alone supplies full revelation.  But as I hear different scholars speak on how many New Testament motifs have a detailed antecedent, in second temple Jewish writings; it seems as I read these writers, the concepts almost align perfectly. For example

Rev. 20:13 The sea gave up the dead that were in it, and Death and
Hades gave up the dead that were in them, and each one was judged
according to his deeds. 14 Then Death and Hades were thrown into the
lake of fire. This is the second death—the lake of fire.

And we read

1 Enoch 50:1 In those days, the earth will return what has been
entrusted to it, and Sheol will also return what it has received, and
the underworld will return what it owes. 2 He will choose the
righteous and holy from among them: for the day is near when they
shall be saved.

Should one read these text to gain a better understanding of themes found in the Holy Bible? I heard that 1 Enoch is a Babylonian interpretation, as is the Talmud. So can one gain information from these second Temple text, and still come to a correct interpretation of motifs found within the protestant Canon?

The Bible has a number of recommended readings and it also assumes foreknowledge of certain events which it condenses into a few verses rather than elaborating on it because it assumes the audience is very familiar with the narrative. Many NT authors and also Jesus make references, paraphrase or directly quote from non Protestant canonical OT books. Until 1885 the KJV had 80 books not 66 but they were reduced to save the printing press money.

@Nihil, Both the Geneva Bible of 1560 and the King James Version of 1611 contained 66 books along with a separate section with 14 books in the apocrypha. These books contain  a variety of teachings, including the claim that benevolent giving absolves ALL sin (a concept rejected by Jesus Christ himself), historical accounts, and a bit of incredibly profound wisdom (I'm joking) that I've remembered to this day--namely that a certain dog was deemed exceedingly happy because it waggeth its tail!

Also note that in 1 Enoch 50:4, we read "In those days the mountains shall skip like rams, and the hills shall leap like young sheep satiated with milk; and all the righteous shall become angels in heaven. Mountains skipping like rams comes from Psalm 114, but do you believe that the New Testament was influenced to teach that "all the righteous shall become angels in heaven"? There's also the possibility that some of these writings, available only in Greek, may have been revised over time, even after the New Testament was completed.

What do you mean by ,"but do you believe that the New Testament was influenced to teach that "all the righteous shall become angels in heaven"?

Many such writings by Jewish people appeared during the 400 year gap between the last of the OT prophetical books and the time of Christ. They contain a lot of history, for example, about the Maccabees, who resisted Hellenization by invading armies. They also contain some fanciful stuff that, in many places, is at odds with what the older Hebrew scriptures state. So, although the historical parts are useful and give us valuable insights, there is a clear difference between them and what has come to be recognized as scripture inspired by God. Check this link for details:  https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/omitting-the-maccabees/
The Book of Tobit was written by Jewish people during that period. It contains some history about Jewish struggles then, and some fanciful stuff: e.g. Sarah, related to Tobit, prays to God to take her life because of ridicule for marrying 7 times, and each time the demon Asmodeus killed her husband before the marriage could be consummated. It also has superstitions about fish liver and heart protecting from demons. Further it claims that almsgiving alone will save. So, again, although historical parts are useful and give us interesting insights, there is a clear difference between that and what has come to be recognized as scripture inspired by God. The Jewish people themselves did not include it as canonical.
Philo says this of Flavius Josephus, the famous Jewish historian, a priest and a nobleman, who wrote an important treatise in defence of the Jews. It was entitled Contra Apionem and is dated circa AD 100 and quotes parts related to the canon [of Hebrew scriptures]. It deduces from this that

"There are several things to note from these remarks of Josephus. (i)
For him the canon whose verbal form was inviolable was closed and in
fact had been closed from the time of Artaxerxes (465-425 BC) -
essentially the time of Malachi. "The number of 'reliable' books which
allow for no alteration and are the code on which Jewish life is
based... is final... and a sharp line is drawn between them and the
numerous records of the period after Artaxerxes which cannot be fully
trusted" (Katz, p.76). (ii) This closed canon was a canon of 22 books
arranged in three parts - 5 books of Moses, 13 of the prophets and 4
of hymns and practical precepts... his OT canon would be identical
with ours irrespective of how he arranged the books within it."
(p.28).

The Book of Tobit is not included. It speaks of an Archangel Raphael, who does not appear anywhere in the Bible, and the Book of Tobit is not part of the Bible. https://www.gotquestions.org/book-of-Tobit.html  The Mormons, however, believe in this Raphael, who is mentioned in their Doctrine and Covenants.
A unique point about the Bible record is that it is inspired by the Holy Spirit, who Jesus said would “guide us into all truth”. Understanding is given to “those of a contrite spirit and [who] who trembles at my word” – Isaiah 66:2. That is why it is so crucially important to know what constitutes God’s inspired word, and that which does not. For academic study, extra-biblical material may offer background insight into the times and peoples, but to grasp what God would have us know, non-academic, sincerely reverent handling of the Bible as holy, will make us tremble. Beware those who claim to explain the Bible but who do not tremble at it as God’s inspired word.

The answer is yes, if one wants to delve deeper. The Book of Enoch is a good example in terms of understanding the origin of Christian concepts such as paradise and hell. The influence of evil spirits is another example that is not much discussed in the Old Testament itself, but emerges in the intertestamental writings. Fallen angels also appear in this period, including the idea of an archdemon, whether he is known as Satan (NT), Asmodeus (Book of Tobit), Azazel (Book of Enoch) or what-have-you.
Another important resource for studies such as those mentioned in the OP is the Dead Sea Scrolls. These are the richest source of insight pertaining to the particular group that produced them, a group that was certainly known to both Jesus and John the Baptist. Josephus, who wrote in the late fist century, is our best historical source for the period in question, including the history of the kings of Judea prior to the Roman period as well as the emergence of the Pharisees and Sadducees, the growth of messianic expectations, the Herodian dynasty and the Roman administration of Palestine during the time of Jesus and the Book of Acts. The Talmud is later still, but it gives information not found elsewhere about the period in question.
Incidentally, some scholars include much of the Book of Daniel in the category of literature we are discussing - having been produced during the Maccabean revolt of the 2nd c. bce rather than the time of Daniel himself.

@ Dan Fefferman - Yea verily, much background info can be gleaned from extra-biblical sources. However, how we relate them to the origin and evolution of basic doctrine is a "cautionary  tale."--- Concerning comment re Daniel: Although Daniel is placed with the Writings and not the Prophets, in the Hebrew Bible, it is still considered canonical...and not one of the Apocraphal boooks.  And its prophecies ---and fulfilments--- go far beyond the Maccabean period, showing their supernatural nature.  Peace.
